# Firefox: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: https, ssl

### Context

For a self-hosted Nextcloud server running over tor, I'm getting the error listed below, after setting: `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` in `about:config` to: `true` as recommended in [this post](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1197635):

> SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4762977/7437143) seems to suggest that is because there is something wrong with port 443. However, that is for regular sites, I did not do anything with apache, and my `torrc` file contains:

```
...
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/nextcloud/
HiddenServicePort 8080 127.0.0.1:81
```

The `subjectAltName` is defined as:

```
subjectAltName=DNS:localhost,DNS:some_onion.onion
```

And after importing the accompanying `ca.crt` into brave, it successfully provides `https` for https://localhost:81 .

### Question

How can I resolve the SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG for the tor website?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

As implied by [Ben Tasker](https://www.bentasker.co.uk/posts/documentation/linux/309-building-a-tor-hidden-service-from-scratch-part-2-http-and-https.html), It seems the issue was that https over Tor requires port 443, which was not opened by the written code. So the solution was to ensure the `/etc/tor/torrc` file was modified such that it contained:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/nextcloud/
HiddenServicePort 443 127.0.0.1:443
```

Followed by:

```
sudo reload tor
```

(And activating the tor service with:)

```
sudo tor
```

and to visit the onion at: https://some_onion.onion:443

### Code

The full script for supporting https over tor is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Here is the list of certificates and their description:
# First you create your own certificate authority.
CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME="ca-key.pem"
CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME="ca.pem"
# Same file as ca.pem except different file extension and content.
CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME="ca.crt"

# Then you create a SSL certificate.
SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME="cert-key.pem"

# Then create a sign-request (for your own CA to sign your own SSL certificate)
CA_SIGN_SSL_CERT_REQUEST_FILENAME="cert.csr"
SIGNED_DOMAINS_FILENAME="extfile.cnf"

# Then create the signed public SSL cert.
SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME="cert.pem"

# Then merge the CA and SLL cert into one.
MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME="fullchain.pem"

setup_tor_ssl() {
  local onion_address="$1"

  # Create domains accepted by certificate.
  local domains
  #domains="DNS:$onion_address,IP:127.0.0.1"
  #domains="DNS:localhost,IP:$onion_address" # IP onion does not work
  #domains="DNS:*.$onion_address" # Does not work.
  #domains="DNS:$onion_address" # Does not work.
  domains="DNS:localhost,DNS:$onion_address" # Works for localhost
  echo "domains=$domains.end_without_space"

  delete_target_files

  # Generate and apply certificate.
  generate_ca_cert "$CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  generate_ssl_certificate "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_SIGN_SSL_CERT_REQUEST_FILENAME" "$SIGNED_DOMAINS_FILENAME" "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME" "$domains"

  verify_certificates "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"

  merge_ca_and_ssl_certs "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME"

  install_the_ca_cert_as_a_trusted_root_ca "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME"

  add_certs_to_nextcloud "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME" "$MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME"
}

generate_ca_cert() {
  local ca_private_key_filename="$1"
  local ca_public_key_filename="$2"

  # Generate RSA
  openssl genrsa -aes256 -out "$ca_private_key_filename" 4096

  # Generate a public CA Cert
  openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key "$ca_private_key_filename" -out "$ca_public_key_filename"
}

generate_ssl_certificate() {
  local ca_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ca_private_key_filename="$2"
  local ca_sign_ssl_cert_request_filename="$3"
  local signed_domains_filename="$4"
  local ssl_public_key_filename="$5"
  local ssl_private_key_filename="$6"
  local domains="$7"
  # Example supported domains:
  # DNS:your-dns.record,IP:257.10.10.1

  # Create a RSA key
  openssl genrsa -out "$ssl_private_key_filename" 4096

  # Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)
  openssl req -new -sha256 -subj "/CN=yourcn" -key "$ssl_private_key_filename" -out "$ca_sign_ssl_cert_request_filename"

  # Create a `extfile` with all the alternative names
  echo "subjectAltName=$domains" >>"$signed_domains_filename"

  # optional
  #echo extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth >> "$ca_sign_ssl_cert_request_filename"

  # Create the public SSL certificate.
  openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in "$ca_sign_ssl_cert_request_filename" -CA "$ca_public_key_filename" -CAkey "$ca_private_key_filename" -out "$ssl_public_key_filename" -extfile "$signed_domains_filename" -CAcreateserial
}

verify_certificates() {
  local ca_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ssl_public_key_filename="$2"
  openssl verify -CAfile "$ca_public_key_filename" -verbose "$ssl_public_key_filename"
}

merge_ca_and_ssl_certs() {
  local ssl_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ca_public_key_filename="$2"
  local merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename="$3"

  cat "$ssl_public_key_filename" >"$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename"
  cat "$ca_public_key_filename" >>"$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename"
}

install_the_ca_cert_as_a_trusted_root_ca() {
  local ca_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ca_public_cert_filename="$2"

  # The file in the ca-certificates dir must be of extension .crt:
  openssl x509 -outform der -in "$ca_public_key_filename" -out "$ca_public_cert_filename"

  # First remove any old cert if it existed.
  sudo rm "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$ca_public_cert_filename"
  sudo update-ca-certificates

  # TODO: Verify target directory exists.
  # On Debian & Derivatives:
  #- Move the CA certificate (`"$ca_private_key_filename"`) into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt`.
  sudo cp "$ca_public_cert_filename" "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$ca_public_cert_filename"

  # TODO: Verify target file exists.

  # TODO: Verify target file MD5sum.

  # Update the Cert Store with:
  sudo update-ca-certificates
}

add_certs_to_nextcloud() {
  local ssl_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ssl_private_key_filename="$2"
  local merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename="$3"

  # First copy the files into nextcloud.
  # Source: https://github.com/nextcloud-snap/nextcloud-snap/issues/256
  # (see nextcloud.enable-https custom -h command).
  #sudo cp ca.pem /var/snap/nextcloud/current/ca.pem
  sudo cp "$ssl_public_key_filename" /var/snap/nextcloud/current/"$ssl_public_key_filename"
  sudo cp "$ssl_private_key_filename" /var/snap/nextcloud/current/"$ssl_private_key_filename"
  sudo cp "$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename" /var/snap/nextcloud/current/"$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename"

  # CLI sudo /snap/bin/nextcloud.enable-https custom Says:
  sudo /snap/bin/nextcloud.enable-https custom "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$ssl_public_key_filename" "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$ssl_private_key_filename" "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename"
}

delete_target_files() {
  rm "$CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME"
  rm "$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME"
  rm "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  rm "$SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME"
  rm "$CA_SIGN_SSL_CERT_REQUEST_FILENAME"
  rm "$SIGNED_DOMAINS_FILENAME"
  rm "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  rm "$MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME"

}
```

Afterwards you still have to manually load your certificate into your respective browser in `settings>search:certificates>...`